# Putting Devise User ID in Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm looking to put the users ID within my applications URL. I have devise all set up with a default configuration, what I'm trying to accomplish is to have a URL when the user is logged in as the following:

**application.com/*userid*/*page***

and when they're not logged in

**application.com/*page***

Is this possible with Devise?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a route that looks for an :id param, then make sure you pass an :id param when navigating to the route. Here's a simple example:

**routes.rb**

```
get '/page', to: 'pages#page', as: :guest_page
get '/:id/page', to: 'pages#page', as: :user_page
```

**page.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>

  <%= link_to "page for logged in user", user_page_path(current_user) %>

<% else %>

  <%= link_to "page for guest user", guest_page_path %>

<% end %>
```

Also, if have many routes, you will want to extract this logic outside the view into a helper method or decorator.

Comment: I currently only allow users to browse if they're logged in, but have a welcome/landing page. So this works quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Actually is more routing than devise.
Scope your routes

```
scope path: ":account_id", as: "account" do
  resources :projects
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html